# Error al momento de instalar npm (npm WARN deprecated)

Tags: nodejs, angular, npm, github, terminal

Al momento de ingresar el código `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`, al parecer me aparece el error de **npm WARN deprecated**, como se muestra a continuación:

```
➜  ~ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Password:
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 239 packages in 20s

20 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

Desinstale NodeJs y lo volvi a instalar pero al parecer me volvia aparecer lo mismo, espero que me puedan ayudar con una solución y por cierto soy usuario Mac Os.

Comment: No es un error, es un *warning* (aviso): angular-cli tiene como dependencias dos librerías que han sido marcadas como *deprecated* (desaconsejadas), porque ya no reciben mantenimiento y se consideran *anticuadas*. No es un problema en sí mismo.

Comment: ¿Saben como se corrige, si como dice @PabloLozano es un aviso, como se hace para que no aparezca?